# How to run a vba macro for multiple excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I am a naive user of VBA and I am looking for a VBA macro which would do the following task

1. Delete 3 tabs from the file and delete the first 6 rows from remanining tabs.
2. Perform this for all the excel files (2013) and save as xlsx in the same or different file folder.

I tried the code available on this link 
[Run same excel macro on multiple excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766238/run-same-excel-macro-on-multiple-excel-files)

At the line 
`Filename=Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")` , I am getting an error which says `run time error "52" Bad file name or number`.

I have changed this:

```
Pathname = "\C:\Users\Desktop\test\try\"\
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's your only problem, but

`\C:\Users\Desktop\test\try\`

should be

`C:\Users\Desktop\test\try\` (without the first backslash)

*I realize this should be a comment--I'm under 50 rep, however.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked as expected. I saved the macro code as test.xlsm and tried to run it again on new set of excel files where it failed and gave me the same error as I have mentioned in my actual question. I am not sure how can use the same macro again n again.