# Run Access VBA in all Access files in folder

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been trying to figure out a way to run the following VBA code on all of the files I have in a folder without having to manually open each file.

This is the code I have right now (exports the desired table as a delimited txt file, including column names):

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()

    Dim MyObj, MySource As Object, File As Variant, stDocName As String, Counter As Integer

    On Error GoTo Err_Command4_Click
        Dim stDocName As String, Counter As Integer
        Counter = 1
        stDocName = "tblSCTurCount"
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", stDocName, "C:\Users\name\Downloads\cnt\cnt_output.txt", True

    Exit_Command4_Click:
        Exit Sub

    Err_Command4_Click:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume Exit_Command4_Click

End Sub
```

When researching the problem, I found [a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766238/run-same-excel-macro-on-multiple-excel-files) that works in excel, but I'm not sure how to do the variables change in access, especially the workbook references.

Thank you!

EDIT -- Code that worked:

```
Dim FS As FileSystemObject
Set FS = New FileSystemObject
Dim MyFolder As Folder
Set MyFolder = FS.GetFolder("C:\Users\name\Downloads\cnt\Folder")
Dim MyFile As File
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

For Each MyFile In MyFolder.Files
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase (MyFile.Path)
    appAccess.Visible = True
    NewFileName = MyFile.Path & ".txt"
    appAccess.DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", "tblScTurCount", NewFileName, True
    appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
Next
```

Comment: But I didn't understand it entirely. Are you using Access or Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the `FileSystemObject`.

For that you will have to add a `reference` the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library. (Go to tools > references... in the VBA editor)

```
Sub test()
    Dim FS As FileSystemObject
    Set FS = New FileSystemObject

    Dim MyFolder As Folder
    Set MyFolder = FS.GetFolder("C:\path\of\the\folder")

    Dim MyFile As File
    For Each MyFile In MyFolder.Files
        'do what you want to do with each file

        'to use the file name:
        MyFile.Name

        'I suppose you have to:
        Application.OpenCurrentDatabase MyFile.Path
        '(please verify if this path contains the filename and extension too). 

         'But create a different filename for each txt:
         NewFileName = MyFile.Path + ".txt"

        'Then you do:
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", "tblScTurCount", NewFileName, True

    Next
End Sub
```

Considering you are using VBA **in Access**, use the [Application.OpenAccessProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff837249.aspx) or the [Application.OpenCurrentDatabase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff837226.aspx) methods to open files in Access.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, on `Set MyFolder = FS.GetFolder("C:\path\of\the\folder")` I am getting "Run-Time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

For reference, I have added the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library and have changed "C:\path\of\the\folder" to the actual path of my folder.

Thank you again!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'll update it, forgot to `create` the FS object.

Comment: I think it's almost there, I'm just unsure how to use the variable `MyFile` in the `DoCmd.TransferText` statement in the op. Specifically, how do I run that command on the table in MyFile (the tables are all named "tblSCTurCount"). I've also edited the original post to show what my current code looks like

Comment: Are you using Access or Excel? I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is `DoCmd` ?

Comment: `MyFile` is one of the files in the directory. It has many properties you can see with `MyFile.` (type a period after MyFile). It has `Name`, `Path` and other properties you can get.

Comment: I'm using Access. I'm writing code to export a specific table (tblScTurCount) from several access databases in a folder into individual .txt files. `DoCmd.TransferText` is the method that creates the .txt export. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I suppose you must do that sequence I added.

Comment: I believe this is the right track, so thank you again. This time I am getting "Run-time error '7867: You already have the database open." even though it is referencing an unopened database. I am taking an hour break so I'll look into this further when I get back

Comment: Looking at the links and the `return type` of the open methods (nothing is returned), it seem an access application can only handle **one** database at a time. You can either close the current database or create a `New Application`

Comment: Thank you so much. I got everything working and have updated the op with the final code