# Open, rename and run same excel macro on multiple excel files

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have about 50 Excel sheets in one folder, on my MacBook - (/Users/myusername/Desktop/Tidy/folder")

I want to perform the following Macro on them all:

```
Sub SmartCopy()
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Set s1 = Sheets("s1")
Set s2 = Sheets("s2")
N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row
j = 1
For i = 1 To N
    If s1.Cells(i, "Y").Value = "No" Then
    Else
        s1.Cells(i, "Y").EntireRow.Copy s2.Cells(j, 1)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

I am struggling to get the sheets to open, almost like the filepath won't be recognised, also each sheet is named like this:

business-listing-002-w-site.csv

with one tab:

business-listing-002-w-site.csv

So I also need to either 1) rename the sheet each time 2) have the macro just open the only sheet in the workbook.

I want to copy all data from all workbooks into one master. I did try to add my Macro and adapt this one but just can't get it to run at all.

[link to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766238/run-same-excel-macro-on-multiple-excel-files)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the workbook (file), not just the sheet(tab).

```
Dim filePath as String
Dim sheetStart as String
Dim count as Integer
Dim sheetEnd as string
Dim thisSheet as Worksheet
Dim wb1 as Workbook
Dim ws1 as Worksheet


filePath = "/Users/myusername/Desktop/Tidy/folder/"
sheetStart = "business-listing-"
sheetEnd = "-w-site"
Set thisSheet as ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")


For count = 1 to 44 'the range of sheets you have
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(filePath & sheetStart & format(count, "000") & sheetEnd & ".csv")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(sheetStart & format(count, "000") & sheetEnd)

    'move the ranges you want from ws1 to thisSheet

    wb1.close
next count
```

each time the code loops, it will change the filename being opened and the sheet that it is looking for.

I assume you either know or can find how to copy a range from ws1 to the next available row of thisSheet based on the original code you provided.

*edited with improved code based on comments*

Comment: I still cannot get this to work. To put it in simple terms, I need to loop through lots of workbooks which I do not know the name of, I also do not know the name of the only tab in each one. I then need to sort the data by looking for column J and finding any 'no' entries in that column and only selecting these rows, then placing them all on one mastersheet.

Comment: Are the names in any logical order? ie business-listing-002-site-w, business-listing-003-site-w, ..004... etc.?

Comment: They are actually yes, but I thought there would be a way to just open any file in the folder. Of course, I'll take any solution! The actual files are from "business-listing-000-w-site" to "business-listing-041-w-site", appreciate your help.