# Applying master workbook VBA to 1000 files

Tags: excel, vba

Following the instructions [in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766238/run-same-excel-macro-on-multiple-excel-files), I tried to run my macro with the following code:

```
Sub ay1()
Dim fileName, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Pathname = "/Users/ayy/Downloads/Folder1/STATS1/"
fileName = Dir(Pathname & "*.csv")
Do While fileName <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & fileName)
    DoWork wb
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    fileName = Dir()
Loop
End Sub

Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)

With wb
    
    Selection.AutoFilter
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$191").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
            Range("C2:C190").Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Delete
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$96").AutoFilter Field:=3
            Range("E95").Select
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWindow.Close

    End With
End Sub
```

I saved this in a "master workbook" that is macro-enabled in the same directory where all my .csv files are located. I clicked run macro and selected ay1.

This is not running on any of my files. I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Are you missing the drive in your pathname?  Or are you maybe on a Mac?  Also - the `With` block in `DoWork` isn't doing anything.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Mac. I'm a little confused, why is the With block in DoWork not doing anything? @TimWilliams

Comment: When you use `With` you use a leading `.` to tie references inside the `With` block to the object which is the subject of the `With` statement.   Since your're on a Mac - you should note that wildcards are not supported with `Dir()`   - you need to loop over all the files and check their names to find the ones you want.  **EDIT** - I guess it does work now on Office 2016+

Comment: I am working on an Office 2016+, so if that's the case and Dir isn't an issue.. what might be the issue do you think?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Does your code detect any files?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `With` block: you need to tie your references to `wb` with a leading `.`

```
Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)

    With wb.Sheets(1)
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter
        .Range("$A$1:$C$191").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
        .Range("C2:C190").EntireRow.Delete
        .Range("$A$1:$C$96").AutoFilter Field:=3
    End With
    wb.Save
    wb.Close
End Sub
```